# FontAwesome icon fonts jagged in latest Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm loading font awesome using the standard method via bootstrap CDN and the icons are not smooth like they are on fontawesome.io

I've tried turning on/off all the styles being applied. I've also tried forcing AA, using shadows to turn-on AA, and several different webkit styles. None of them seemed to work.

You can view the implementation on www.gigyastaging.com (the YOUTUBE play icon in the slider) You can also scroll to the bottom of the page, social icons (inspect and increase the font-size to see the aforementioned jaggedness).

Comment: Just a thought, FontAwesome is an iconic font (regular text), so it will apply the styles according CSS, so can you check if it is some style that is interfering?

Comment: I tried this (mentioned in post) but couldn't isolate any conflicting styles.

Comment: the site looks fine to me. different browsers/OSs will use different font rendering modules (at least on Windows) so it may be browser-specific

Comment: Yeh. Just confirmed what @StephenThomas said.

Comment: This is true, it looks fine on a few other browsers I tested but on my specific machine running latest chrome and windows 7 it looks like crud however fontawesome.io looks fine. Has to be something causing this.. Here is a screencap of what I see on my machine: http://i.imgur.com/LVY5hKq.png

Comment: I'll also add it's bothering the shit out of me dev bros!

Comment: Looks like it's loading the wrong font type. Try disabling all other scripts (just to make sure) and find out which font is actually being loaded.

Comment: Did you have find out what was causing this issue?

Comment: Nevermind. Found the answer here. Worked perfectly http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/#fix